# How to stop \insertfootnote from overriding first footnote

Tags: beamer, footnotes

I am trying to create a nice footnote environment for beamer poster however the textblock lay on top of each other is there anyway I can put all footnotes in the single textblock.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[overlay,absolute]{textpos}
\renewcommand*\footnoterule{}


\setlength{\TPHorizModule}{0.965\paperwidth}
\setlength{\TPVertModule}{\paperheight}
\setbeamertemplate{footnote}{%
\begin{textblock}{1}[0,1](0.02,1)%
\begin{block}{References}
\makebox[2ex][l]{\insertfootnotemark}\footnotesize\insertfootnotetext\par 
\end{block}   
\end{textblock}%
%
}


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
it puts this \footnote{this} under that \footnote{that}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I want both foot notes to just appear as a list not be super imposed on each other.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of removing the `footnoterule` you could use it to place your "footnote headline":

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\renewcommand*\footnoterule{%
    \usebeamercolor[fg]{block title}%
    \usebeamerfont{block title}%    
    Refereces%
    \vskip.5\baselineskip%
}

\setbeamertemplate{footnote}
{
  \parindent 1em\noindent%
  \raggedright
  \hbox to 0.4em{\hfil\insertfootnotemark}\insertfootnotetext\par%
}


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
it puts this \footnote{this} under that \footnote{that}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]